# IntelliJ ALT+Enter doesn't show correctly on the first key press

Tags: flutter, dart, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin, dart-analyzer

I recently updated IntelliJ to 2021.3 Community Edition and I'm using the latest Dart and Flutter plugins.

Whenever I press ALT+Enter to open the context menu (for example if a needed library is not imported), it doesn't show all the expected options the first time. Instead, I get something like this:

[image]

If I close it and open it a second time, it's the same. But if I open it a third time, it works as expected:

[image]

It's as if it takes a while to compute which options should be shown. I never experienced this before upgrading (from a very old 2018 version).

Any ideas?

Comment: Code completion, highlighting, quick fixes and other code insight features in Dart/Flutter projects are powered by the Dart Analysis Server, a tool from the Dart SDK; looks as if the analysis server response is slow; I'd suggest reporting the issue to https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues

Comment: I also experience this after updating the android studio to bumble bee (Intellij 2021.1.1). It was fine on arctic fox (intellij 2020.3.1).